# List the names of customers and the number of orders placed by customers who have placed more than 4 orders

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables:

1. `customer`: `cust_id` and `details of customer address`
2. `order`- `ord_id`, `cust_id`, `ord_quantity`

For one `cust_id` there are many `orders` i.e many `ord_id`

Comment: show us how far you have gone to achieve the desired output and post your create table code.

Comment: School assignment? Don't forget that if we do it for you, you'll learn much less.

Comment: This query only shows customer name but I need number of orders with that---------------select cust_name
     from customer
     where cust_id in (
     select cust_id 
     from ord 
     group by cust_id 
     having count(ord_id) >4);

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    o.total_order
FROM    customer c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        cust_id,
        count(*) AS total_order
    FROM ORDER
    GROUP BY cust_id
    HAVING count(*) > 4
) o 
ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
WHERE
    o.cust_id IS NOT NULL;
```

It should return desire result

Comment: Why a `LEFT JOIN` plus a `IS NOT NULL` instead of a simple `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Just wait until the teacher is asking OP the same question... Hilarious!